# Command line menu with different layers in c++

Tags: c++, command-line, menu, submenu

i am a total amateur and i hit a wall. I thought a couple of hours before i decided to post, before that i tried to find the failure myself.

I'm a larper and i'm in Post-Apocalyptic stuff and tried to program a little tool just as an effect for an event, but even if the compiler doesn't show any errors, there is something wrong.

I'm trying to make a menu with different layers. A Start layer which goes to the real menu-layer, from there i can choose which way i wanna go to show a pre-programmed status, but there is the thing. It doesn't matter which choice i made, i always land on the real-menu-layer. The start works, i can choose to go to the real menu or to quit. But after that 1-3 directly goes to the same menu and 4 produces a memoryaccess failure and the whole thing crashes.

Somewhere i did somethin wrong and i am not able to find the failure.
I'm using fedora LXDE and on windows i use code::blocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

void menu();
void mainMenu();
void erstes();
void erstesMenu();
void aktuell();
void aktuellMenu();
void verteilungMenu();
void verteilung();
void wartungMenu();
void wartung();
int choice1 = 0;
int choice2 = 3;



int main(int argc, char** argv) {



    menu();



    return 0;
}

void mainMenu(void) {

    system("clear");
    cout << "   ---- Alexandria Powermanagement -----\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   ... Geothermales Kraftwerkt entdeckt\n";
    cout << "   ... Veraltetes Betriebssystem entdeckt\n";
    cout << "   ... Überschreibe Steuerung\n";
    cout << "   ... Übertrage Administrative Steuerung auf aktuelles Interface\n";
    cout << "   ... Trenne lokales Benutzerinterface\n";
    cout << "\n";
    usleep(3000000);
    cout << "   ... Fertig ...\n";
    cout << "\n";
    usleep(3000000);
    system("clear");
    cout << "   Erfolgreich\n";
    cout << "   Fortfahren? Ja = 1 / Nein = 2\n";
    cout << "   Eingabe: ";
        cin >> choice1;

    }

void menu(){

        do {
        choice2 = 0;
        mainMenu();

        switch(choice1) {

            case 1:
                erstes();
        break;

            case 2:
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "Für die Republik! Für die Zukunft!\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            default:
                cout << "   Ungültige Eingabe\n";
                break;

        }
        }   while(choice1 != 2);
}

void erstesMenu(void) {

//  do
        {


    cout << "   -- Willkommen Agent Skydd --\n";
        usleep(1000000);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   (1) - Statusabfrage\n";
    cout << "   (2) - Stromverteilung\n";
    cout << "   (3) - Wartungsarbeiten\n";
    cout << "   (4) - Beenden\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   Eingabe: ";
            cin >> choice2;
    }
//  while(choice2 != 4);
    }

void erstes() {

    do {
        erstesMenu();

        switch(choice2) {

            case 1:
                aktuellMenu();
                break;

            case 2:
                verteilungMenu();
                break;

            case 3:
                wartungMenu();
                break;

            case 4:
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Für die Republik! Für die Zukunft!\n";
        cout << "\n";
                break;

            default:
        cout << "   Ungültige Eingabe\n";
                break;
        }

    } while(choice1 != 4);
}

void verteilungMenu(void) {


    cout << "\n";
    cout << "---------- Stromverteilung ----------\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   (1) - Priorisierung\n";
    cout << "   (2) - Aktuelle Verteilung\n";
    cout << "   (3) - Zurück\n";
    cout << "   Eingabe: ";
            cin >> choice2;
    cout << "\n";

}

void verteilung() {

    do {
        verteilungMenu();

        switch(choice2){

            case 1:
                cout << "   1. Verteidigung\n";
                cout << "   2. Medizinische Versorgung\n";
                cout << "   3. Bevölkerung\n";
                break;

            case 2:
            cout << "   Abwehrstellungen mit 7%\n";
            cout << "   Medical Chorps 10%\n";
            cout << "   T-Force 10%\n";
                cout << "13% bei aktueller Auslastung zur freien Verfügung\n";
                break;

            case 3:
        cout << "\n";
                break;

            default:
        cout << "   Ungültige Eingabe\n";
                break;

        }

    } while(choice2 != 3);


}



void wartungMenu(void) {



    cout << "----------  Wartungsmenü   ----------\n";
    cout << "   (1) - Status\n";
    cout << "   (2) - Wartung starten\n";
    cout << "   (3) - Back\n";
    cout << "   Eingabe: ";
            cin >> choice2;
}

void wartung() {

    do {
        wartungMenu();

        switch(choice2){

            case 1:
                cout << "   Turbine 1 wird im 6 Stündigen Wechsel die Auslastung mit Turbine 2 tauschen.\n";
                cout << "   Es wird Empfohlen diesen Zeitraum unberührt zu lassen um gleichmäßige Downtime der Turbinen zu gewährleisten\n";
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "   Wartungszyklus gestartet\n";
                cout << "   Während der Wartung kann es vereinzelt zu Schwankungen im Stromnetz kommen. Wir bitten um Ihr Verständnis.\n";
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            default:
                cout << "   Ungültige Eingabe\n";
                break;

        }

    } while(choice2 != 3);


}



void aktuellMenu(void) {

        {

    cout << "---------- Statusabfrage ----------\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   (1) - Turbine 1\n";
    cout << "   (2) - Turbine 2\n";
    cout << "   (3) - Turbine 3\n";
    cout << "   (4) - Zurück\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Eingabe: ";
            cin >> choice2;
    }

    }

void aktuell() {

    do {
        aktuellMenu();

        switch(choice2) {

            case 1:
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "   Turbine 1 auf 35% Leistung\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "   Turbine 2 auf 5% Leistung\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case 3:
                usleep(5000000);
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "   Turbine 3 Offline\n";
                usleep(1000000);
                cout << "   Fehlermeldung wird angezeigt:\n";
                usleep(500000);
                cout << "   Durch Schaden verursachter technischer Defekt\n";
                cout << "   Schadensmeldung:\n";
                usleep(1000000);
                cout << "   Zuleitung:      Defekt\n";
                usleep(500000);
                cout << "   Regenerator:    Defekt\n";
                usleep(500000);
                cout << "   Kondensator:    Defekt\n";
                usleep(500000);
                cout << "   Pumpe:          Defekt\n";
                cout << "\n";
                break;

            case 4:
                cout <<"\n";
                break;


            default:
                cout << "   Ungültige Eingabe\n";
                break;

        }

    } while(choice2 != 4);
}
```

I know, not pretty but for my first try, i think, i could have done worse. And yes, the output text is german. And yes, i never wrote c++ before.

I hope you guys can help me and i bet the solution is simple but i just don't see it (i think, when i read the solution, i will facepalm myself).

I hope you guys will help me :-)

Comment: In `erstes` you probably wanted `switch(choice2)`, not `switch(choice1)`. Either that or read into `choice1` in `erstesMenu`. Also your loop in `erstesMenu` will just keep going until the user enters 4, which is probably not what you meant, get rid of the loop, you call `erstesMenu` on every iteration of `erstes` anyway.

Comment: Somehow i don't understand what exactly you mean right now. To be honest, most of the part i guessed or found here and i tried to adapt it to my needs. Could it be, that i need a choice3 for the next layer? Like i said, i really have no idea right now.

Comment: Why do you have a `do`-`while` loop in `erstesMenu`? This is why it will keep asking you until you enter 4. Later on, in `erstes`, you check `choice1`, but the variable you read into in `erstesMenu` is `choice2`.

Comment: Also, you branch to functions like `erstesMenu()`, but those only set the value of `choice2` and you probably meant to call `erstes()`. The classic approach to this would be to make a list of the states the program could be in, and have the menu functions return the state the program should enter next.  Each menu then becomes a state.

Answer (score 0):

```
void erstesMenu(void) {

    do {


    cout << "   -- Willkommen Agent Skydd --\n";
        usleep(1000000);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   (1) - Statusabfrage\n";
    cout << "   (2) - Stromverteilung\n";
    cout << "   (3) - Wartungsarbeiten\n";
    cout << "   (4) - Beenden\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "   Eingabe: ";
            cin >> choice2;
    } while(choice2 != 4);
    }

void erstes() {

    do {
        erstesMenu();

        switch(choice1) {

            case 1:
                aktuellMenu();
                break;

            case 2:
                verteilungMenu();
                break;

            case 3:
                wartungMenu();
                break;

            case 4:
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Für die Republik! Für die Zukunft!\n";
        cout << "\n";
                break;

            default:
        cout << "   Ungültige Eingabe\n";
                break;
        }

    } while(choice1 != 4);
}
```

Here you cin choice2 in erstesMenu(), but then in erstes() you switch according to choice1, not 2. That might be the problem.

Comment: Changed it and now it doesn't crash and erstes works fine, but every menu after that just leads back to erstes.